# Why is my CPU limited after sleep or hibernation?

Tags: windows-10, cpu, sleep, hibernate, hp-pavilion

I run Windows 10 x64 Build 1511 on a HP Pavilion dv6 with Intel Dual Core at 2.27GHz.  Every time I sleep or hibernate my computer and wake it up, it runs at 0.77GHz or 1.56GHz, which makes my computer run really slow. I also cannot use fast startup now because this occurs.

PS:- When I have 0.77GHz, I put it into sleep and wake it again, it goes to 1.56GHz. Sometimes, it automatcally goes to 1.56GHz. It is kind of random what speed goes to but most of time it goes to 0.77GHz.

Comment: Are you 100% sure about this? Hibernation and sleep are quite different, how do you measure CPU speed? Did you check for some processes taking CPU on background?

Comment: Yes, I am. I measure this using Task Manager and WinProcess (or something like that from the Technet .zip) Nope, all the processes are struggling for processor and everything is at a crawl. I edited my question with some extra info. Thanks.

Comment: Can you check the power option setting? It has different performance settings for cpu or etc. Please check it and let me know

Comment: @MahdiRafatjah I can't find any option like that in Power Options. Could you please tell me where it may be?

Comment: Just put the power option to high performance, check that graphic card is installed, if you have second graphic make sure of that too. And on the power option system settings make sure all shutdown settings are marked

Comment: @MahdiRafatjah That is all set already.

Comment: Please check windows event viewer. I don't know what is it but i'm really need to know

Comment: Can you use diagnostic startup (run > msconfig > general > ) and tell me the result ?

Comment: @MahdiRafatjah Event Viewer entries are normal. Will try the diag startup when I can. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Disconnect power adapter to laptop, connect it again.

**More information**

Had the same issue with my dell laptop running windows 8.1.
After waking up from sleep and checking the CurrentClockSpeed of the cpu it reported as 800 (used command line tool wmic to check this)

```
c:\>wmic
wmic:root\cli>cpu get CurrentClockSpeed
CurrentClockSpeed
800
```

While the MaxClockSpeed is 2801

```
wmic:root\cli>cpu get MaxClockSpeed
MaxClockSpeed
2801
```

I know that the power options will affect performance so first I tried to change current power option to High Performance but no change.
Then I just **pulled the power cord and inserted it again** and suddenly, the CurrentClockSpeed reports normal again.

```
wmic:root\cli>cpu get CurrentClockSpeed
CurrentClockSpeed
2801
```

Comment: Thanks!  Just checked, and this probably the problem. Unfortunately, I can't really use this solution as I don't have a battery. Marking this as the answer as it probably will work for anyone else having the same problem.

Comment: Perhaps there is another way to trigger the energy saving function that sets the current clock speed for a stationary machine...

Comment: Hmm... Perhaps something that would make the computer think it lost power?

Comment: This simple solution also worked for me in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem and I didn't found a solution, but a workaround:
Go into the Windows Power options and select another energy plan (like `Balanced`) and after this switch back to your original plan.

This will trigger the same function as in Dans answer and the cpu clock should be normal after this.